fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied while doing aws s3 cp
I am trying to copy some object from AWS s3 following a tutorial with this command: aws s3 cp s3://wildrydes-us-east-1/WebApplication/1_StaticWebHosting/website ./ --recursive
and it gave me this error:  fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
I tried to edit my permission policy and it's now like this:
{
    "Version": "version_id",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "some_id",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

but it still gives me this same error.
I don't have MAF enabled and I only have 1 user in my account

When selecting your region in the first step of the tutorial, did you use us-east-1 or a different region? If you're using a different region, you need to edit the aws s3 cp command to that region bucket instead

If you're using the same region, I think there could be some issues with the permission policy of that s3 bucket so you might need to reach out AWS to support

It is giving me the same error, and I tried multiple region names. I have reported the problem via the Feedback link on that page. Not much you can do unless you can find the files somewhere on GitHub from people who have previous done the Lab.

@JohnRotenstein Thank you! But at the same time is there any other way I could get the source code that is used in this tutorial?
